# How to retrive geopoint from MyLocationNewOverlay using OSMdroid

Tags: java, android, location, osmdroid, mylocationoverlay

Using MyLocationNewOverlay I can show user's current location in my mapview.

```
 mylocation = new MyLocationNewOverlay(mapView);
            mylocation.enableMyLocation();
            mylocation.enableFollowLocation();
            IMyLocationProvider s= mylocation.getMyLocationProvider();
            mylocation.getMyLocation();
            mapView.getOverlays().add(mylocation);
```

To create a route, I've tried to get user's current location by mylocation.getMyLocation /mylocation.getLastFix() but both return null. How to retrive the geopoint/lat long points?

Answer (score 1):

If you used `mylocation.getMyLocation()` and it returned `null` it's because you didn't leaved it enough time to find your location.

If we take a look at the source code here:

```
public GeoPoint getMyLocation() {
    if (mLocation == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return new GeoPoint(mLocation);
    }
}
```

You get null simply because your location is actually null, same goes for `mylocation.getLastFix()`

```
public Location getLastFix() {
    return mLocation;
}
```

Make sure you wait at least for `runOnFirstFix` to end before trying to get your location.

Also, the line:

```
IMyLocationProvider s= mylocation.getMyLocationProvider();
```

is unnecessary in this context, aside from that, you should be on the right track.